# Swift expanding Tableview cell how to adjust height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hope that somebody can help me, thank you already anyway. So realized an expanding Tableview cell (when i tap the cell it open with more detail) and now i want to adjust the height the cell, how i have to do? because before the cell i want to put an image with a description and i want the cell not on the top but at the end of my controller, i tried to put an imagine in my view controller but i have a error in my code, what code i need for adjust the height and put an image with description before the cell?

```
class PROVAViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableViewData = [cellData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        tableViewData = [cellData(opened: false, title: "Title1", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Title1", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Title1", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"]),
                         cellData(opened: false, title: "Title1", sectionData: ["Cell1","Cell2","Cell3"])]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return tableViewData.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableViewData[section].opened == true {
            return tableViewData[section].sectionData.count + 1
        } else {
            return 1
        }

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
            return cell

        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
            cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]
            return cell
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
                tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = false
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none) // play around with it(cosa significa non lo so, vedi video)

            }else{
                tableViewData[indexPath.section].opened = true
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)

            }
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: it depends on how your tableView is set up. When using Automatic Dimension, think its default, than the content of the cell needs to be aligned with specific constraints on top and bottom. If the content of the label will grow, than the cell will automatically grow. Means, if you tap the cell, and store the isOpen property like you already do, in the cellForRow you need to check it and place the other content. For manual height, u have to check your datasource in heightForRow func and change it for opened cells

Answer (score 0):

Set the top, bottom, leading, and trailing for the label, also set **number of lines** to **0**.set the tableview height to **UITableViewAutomaticDimension**. This will make the label and cell grow according to the content.

[image: ScreenShot 1]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if understood you question Correctly:

Your cell has and `imageView` with a `UILabel` next to it with dynamic content.

You can use the following logic.

**Step:- 1** Make sure the row size is changed at both the places as shown on Screen shots:

[image]
[image]

**Step:- 2** Drag an `imageView` and `label` into cell and get it done with following constraints:

[image]

Hope this helps.